# Custom filter messages for specific columns in Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Let's say we have a grid like in this Telerik example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/UkiH/2

Default info message for grid filter is: 'Show items with value that:'

Is there a way to change that message for only one specific column in grid, and others to remain with default messages?

Something like:

```
columns: [{
    field: "OrderID",
    title: "Order ID",
    width: 120
}, {
    field: "ShipCountry",
    title: "Ship Country"
}, {
    field: "ShipName",
    title: "Ship Name"
}, {
    field: "ShipAddress",
    filterable: true,
    messages: {
        info: 'Show items custom message:'
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define `messages` inside `filterable`. Something as follows:

```
{
    field: "ShipAddress",
    filterable: {
        messages: {
            info: 'Show items custom message:'
        }
    }
}
```